# build multidimensional array from strings or array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

let's say I have an array like so:

```
$my_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

How do I build a multidimensional array using the values from    $my_array

My array should look like this:

```
$my_new_array = $new_array['a']['b']['c']['d'];
```

or

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
    (
        [b] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
            (
                [d] => Array
                (

                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? I know you could accomplish this very easily with a [recursive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 2):

```
$my_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$size     = sizeof($my_array);
$output   = array();

for ( $i = $size - 1; $i >= 0; --$i ) {
  $output = array( $my_array[$i] => $output );
}

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["a"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["b"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["c"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["d"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative, going from external to internal during the creation process:

```
$my_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$multidimensional_array = array();
$array_reference = &$multidimensional_array;

foreach ( $my_array as $value ) {
    $array_reference = &$array_reference[$value];
} 

$array_reference = array();

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($multidimensional_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: `$array_reference[$value] = array();` inside your loop is not needed.

Comment: Yes, but this line $array_reference = array(); must be added at the end of foreach, otherwise, the most inner array reference will be NULL